# Can't import css style in React application

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

Hello I have problem with import css in React application and I don't know what is wrong in my code:

Error:

133:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: D:\src\styles\styles.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
|*{
|     color:red;
| }
    at eval (133:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:979)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (app.js?bd9c:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:737)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:405)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:63
    at bundle.js:66
```

styles.css (only test file):

```
*{
color:red;
}
```

webpack config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports={
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer:{
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

.babelrc :

```
{
    "presets":[
        "env",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins":[
        "transform-class-properties"   
    ]
}
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/styles.css';
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I dont have idea what is wrong ;?

Comment: How are you running the app, does it run successfully if you remove the `css` import ?

Comment: I use yarn run dev-server in console, yes if i delete css code it run successfully

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: could you explain why would that fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports={
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, 
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer:{
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    }
};
```

Also, try changing your css.

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Just to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways you can solve this.

Add to your "loaders" in package.json

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
```

Add to your "rules" in package.json

```
{ test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers. I don't know why but after restrting my computer, my first version suddenly it's working... 
I think that I need to clean my computer :)